# How to package external jars to runnable jar with maven

Tags: maven, executable-jar

I use a runnable jar which classes make use for example of a mysql-connector.jar and a log4j.jar.

How do i pack these external jar's into the runnable jar? Or dont i have to do this anyway and i can access them otherwise?

At the moment i am starting the runnable jar like this:
java -jar /tomcat/webapps/TestApp/Test.jar

May i just add a -classpath to my java call and put all needed libraries into this call or into the Manifest!?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to package the dependencies in jar using maven?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13352098/how-to-package-the-dependencies-in-jar-using-maven)

Comment: If this is for external distribution, be careful about bundling the GPL-licensed mysql connector, though. Better (safer) to ask the user to download it by himself.

Comment: It will just run on my server so no one is going to be downloading it.

Comment: Then take a look at the linked question. I like the onejar plugin.

Comment: Yeah i am already using the fatjar plugin, but i thought that there is going to be a solution for maven where i dont have to install something like fatjar.

Comment: Well, Maven is installing that for you. The result is the same.

Comment: But i have to configure the fatjar plugin then too.